# Is there a way to disable the welcome screen on 3DSMax 9 64 bit?

Tags: windows-10

My question is: When opening the program running windows 10 the program freezes and I must close it out using the task manager. Has anyone ever had this program with older 3D 64 bit programs while using windows 10?

Comment: Did you install the service pack for that software?....https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/downloads/caas/downloads/content/autodesk-3ds-max-9-service-pack-1.html

Comment: Also see this....https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Troubleshooting-3ds-Max-problems-when-running-under-Windows-10.html

Comment: No I did not but let me try that and see if that solves the problem, thank you for the advice, I will get back to you.

Comment: Be sure to read the second link first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a couple of years ago and gave up. Then gave down a couple of weeks ago when another project came up. Couldn't find anywhere on the Internet to help.

Mine was getting stuck in exactly the same place on the welcome screen. Turned out to be '\3ds Max 9\stdplugs\DxPlugins\DxDDS.bmi' failing to initialise.

I deleted that bmi and Max loaded without too many issues. There did seem to be an issue with update on rotate but I didn't investigate much. Only needed access to some old game mod tools written for Max 9.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).